# ASP.NET MVC 5 with MS SQL Server 2012- Send automated email upon reaching deadline of Quotation Close date

Tags: email, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Microsoft SQL Server 2012. In my application, suppliers are able to submit their quotations online. Now the system requirement is, as soon as the Quotation Close Date(and time) is reached, for e.g. Friday 18th November, 2016 at 5:00pm, the system should send an automated email to the Procurement Manager detailing a list of who all submitted with their prices.

Can someone please explain as to how can I send that automated email. I have done searches online and people are saying to use Windows Service or Quartz.Net or SQL Server Agent but I am not sure how exactly to do that.

For reference, the following is my Quotation class and the table fields are exactly the same as the class attributes. I have a field called "EndDate" that stores the Quotation close date & time:

```
public partial class tblQuotationRequest
{            
        public System.Guid QuotationRequestId { get; set; }
        public string QuotationReferenceNum { get; set; }
        public string Campus { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> QuotationStatusID { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a Windows Service or a scheduled Console Application at all?  MSDN has examples on how to create a Windows Service and how to create a Console Application (the latter of which can be used by any scheduling system).  Where are you actually stuck?

Comment: When you say a Console Application, does it mean I will have to write a Console Application and somehow use the DLL in my MVC application? I already have a MVC application which is 97% complete, just that the last bit where I am supposed to send automated email is where I am stuck.

Comment: No, a Console Application is a separate application entirely from a Web Application.  It runs on the command line.  You'd basically schedule it to run at some regular interval or appointed time.  Don't try to force this into your Web Application, scheduled tasks are a separate thing entirely.

Comment: Thanks @David for that...Now once the scheduler is running, would it be able to send emails? If yes, will it send emails from the Console application or will the SQL Server job send emails? Do you know of any links that I can follow? I am sorry, I am doing this for the 1st time so I am really not sure how and where to start this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After liasing with my colleagues, I created a Scheduled Job in Microsoft SQL Server that runs the Stored Procedure as shown below. What the stored procedure does is checks and pulls all quotations that closed on that day. If there are any, it formats the body content of the email and stores it in a variable @tableHTML.

Then it sends the email(s) using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail command providing the relevant parameters. Please note that you will need to have a email sending profile already configured on your SQL Server. This can be done using Database Mail Configuration Wizard.

Hope this helps.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[p_QUOTATION_CLOSE_SUMMARY] 

AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    SET XACT_ABORT ON  
    BEGIN TRAN  
    DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX);  

        --write your Select query here

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
begin 

SET @tableHTML =
    N'<br>The following Quotations that were due today have been received : <br><br>'+
    N'<table>' +
    N'<tr bgcolor="#004251"><th>Quotation No.</th><th>Campus</th>' +
    N'<th>Department</th><th>Title</th><th>Supplier</th>' +
    N'<th>Currency</th><th>Price</th></tr>' +
    CAST ( ( SELECT td = QuotationReferenceNum, '',
                    td = Campus, '',
                    td = Department, '',
                    td = Title, '',
            td = FirstName, '',
            td = Currency, ''         
    FROM            Table X
    WHERE           <<Your Condition>>
    ORDER BY QuotationReferenceNum ASC 

    FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>' ;


exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='YourProfileName',
    @recipients= 'abc@def.com',
    @copy_recipients = 'xyz@abc.com',
    @blind_copy_recipients = 'def@ghi.com',
    @subject='Quotation Close Summary', 
    @body = @tableHTML,
    @body_format = 'HTML'

end

COMMIT
```